# html form on click do php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've been searching around for an answer to my question.
Many other people have asked the same question but did not get an answer to their question. The question is this.

I have the following code.

```
function follow_button(){
global $wpdb, $bp;
$loguser = $bp->loggedin_user->id;
$disuser = $bp->displayed_user->id;
if($loguser == $disuser){
} else {
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE user = $loguser AND profile = $disuser");
if(empty($results)){
    echo '<form id="followsubmit" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="follow_button" value="follow">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="follow"></form>';
} else {
   echo '<form id="followsubmit" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="unfollow_button" value="unfollow">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="unfollow"></form>';

}
}
if( isset( $_POST['follow'] ) && strlen( $_POST['follow'] )) {follow_function();}
if( isset( $_POST['unfollow'] ) && strlen( $_POST['unfollow'} )) {unfollow_function();}
}
}
```

The above code works fine. But I ran into some problems when I started adding more forms to the same page such as this one listed above. My problem that im having is, if I were to click the Follow (or unfollow) button, all the other forms will also submit.

I realize where my problem was.

```
    if( isset( $_POST['justsomeform'] ) && strlen( $_POST['justsomeform'} )) {justsomeotherfunction();}
```

*note: all my other forms have set value such as the one listed above.*
Because they are all set, and they all have a value, they would call the php function even though I did not click on them.

After researching, onclick I tried to put the function inside the form onclick action.. eg..

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cheese" value="yellocheese">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="' . doafunction() . '" value="I like Cheese"></form>
```

But that didn't work as planned. It would execute the function when the page loads. So I started the quest to find an answer to my problem and came across an example such as..

```
$( "#followsubmit" ).submit(function( event ) {
<?php follow_function(); ?>
event.preventDefault();
});
```

But that didn't work.. So, here I am asking for help.

In-case the question wasn't clear enough or I got a little sidetracked. Here it is again.

I have a html form. When I click "submit" I need a execute a php file.

*note: "if(isset..." will not do.*

Thank you in advance!

**EDITED:**

The following is how all the forms are formatted.

```
function post_options_content(){
if( isset( $_POST['profile_comment_post_button'] ) &&  strlen( $_POST['profile_comment_post_button'] )) {my_comment_content();}
if( isset( $_POST['profile_comment_post_button'] ) && strlen( $_POST['profile_comment_post_button'] )){my_wall_nav_adder();}
if( isset( $_POST['public_comment_post_button'] ) &&  strlen( $_POST['publiccomment_post_button'] )) {my_comment_content();}
if( isset( $_POST['public_comment_post_button'] ) && strlen( $_POST['public_comment_post_button'] )){my_wall_nav_adder();}
if( isset( $_POST['userspost'] ) && strlen( $_POST['userspost'] )) {postdatatodatabase();}
if( isset( $_POST['main_userspost'] ) &&  strlen( $_POST['main_userspost'] )) {main_activity_post_to_database();}
if( isset( $_POST['like'] ) && strlen( $_POST['like'] )) {like_wall_post();}
if( isset( $_POST['removemypost'] ) && strlen( $_POST['removemypost'] )) {removemypost();}
if( isset( $_POST['report_this_post'] ) && strlen( $_POST['report_this_post'] )) {report_this_post();}
if( isset( $_POST['nudge'] ) && strlen( $_POST['nudge'] )) {send_nudge_to_database();}
if( isset( $_POST['unfollow'] ) && strlen( $_POST['unfollow'] )) {unfollow_button_action();}
if( isset( $_POST['follow'] ) && strlen( $_POST['follow'] )) {add_follow_to_database();}
}add_action('post_options', 'post_options_content');
```

I add

```
do_action('post_options');
```

to the bottom of the page or function that is needed.. Here is an example.

```
function main_activity_wall_feed() {
global $wpdb, $bp;
$disuser = $bp->displayed_user->id;
$loguser = $bp->loggedin_user->id;
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
$limit = 15;
$offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
$entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wallpost ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $offset, $limit" );
if( $entries ) {
$count = 1;
$class = '';
    foreach( $entries as $entry ) {
    $class = ( $count % 2 == 0 );
    // vars
    $bpurl = $entry->sendersurl;
    $sendersname = $entry->sendersname;
    $memberavatar = $entry->sendersid;
    $ownersid = $entry->sendersid;
    $hide_me = $entry->anon;
    $messageid = $entry->id;
    $contentmessage = $entry->message;
    $profileid = $entry->profileid;

        if ($hide_me == '1'){
            echo '<div style="float:left;"><img src="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/truth-wall/includes/images/mystery-man-50.jpg"></div>';
            echo '<div id="loopmessage">';
            publicreportanddeletebutton($messageid, $loguser, $ownersid); <-form
            anonwhowrotetowho($ownersid, $profileid, $bpurl, $sendersname, $contentmessage);
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="loopnavbar">';
            publiclikebutton($messageid, $loguser); <- Form
            public_comment_post_button($messageid, $memberavatar); <-Form
            echo '</div>';
            get_wall_comments($messageid);
            post_comment_form($messageid); <-Form
            echo '<hr />';
        }
        if ($hide_me == '0'){
            echo '<div style="float:left;">';
                echo '<a href="' . bp_core_get_user_domain( $memberavatar ) . '">' . bp_core_fetch_avatar ( array( 'item_id' => $memberavatar, 'type' => 'full' ) ) . '</a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="loopmessage">';
                publicreportanddeletebutton($messageid, $loguser, $ownersid); <- Form
                whowrotetowho($ownersid, $profileid, $bpurl, $sendersname, $contentmessage);
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="loopnavbar">';
                publiclikebutton($messageid, $loguser); <-Form
                public_comment_post_button($messageid, $memberavatar);
            echo '</div>'; <- Form
                get_wall_comments($messageid);
                post_comment_form($messageid); <- Form
            echo '<hr />';
        }
$count++;
}
} else {
echo 'No posts yet';
}
$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wallpost" );
$num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'pagenum', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __( '&laquo; Prev', 'aag' ),
'next_text' => __( 'Next &raquo;', 'aag' ),
'total' => $num_of_pages,
'current' => $pagenum
) );

if ( $page_links ) {
echo $page_links;
}
do_action('post_options');
do_action('post_comment_options');
}
?>
```

I would like to use ajax.. But no luck. I am asking for a simple ajax example showing a form with 2 hidden values, when clicked, call a php function.

```
function truth_form() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo '<form action="" method="post">
<center><textarea rows="3" cols="65" maxlength="180" name="userspost"></textarea>
<div style="width:250px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:25px;">
<div style="float:left;"><input type="checkbox" name="hideme" value="1" /> Anonymous!</div>
<div style="float:right;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" /> </div></div></form></center>
<br />';
}
}

function main_truth_form() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $bp;
echo '<form action="" method="post">
<center><textarea placeholder="Remember, be nice!" rows="3" cols="65" maxlength="180" name="main_userspost"></textarea>
<div style="width:250px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:25px;">
<div style="float:left;font-size:15px;"><input type="checkbox" name="hideme" value="1" /> Anonymous!</div>
<div style="float:right;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" /></div></div></form></center>
<br />';
} else {
echo 'Please Log In!';
}
}

function follow_button(){
global $wpdb, $bp;
$loguser = $bp->loggedin_user->id;
$disuser = $bp->displayed_user->id;
if($loguser == $disuser){
} else {
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE user = $loguser AND profile = $disuser");
if(empty($results)){
    echo '<form id="followsubmit" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="follow_button" value="follow">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="follow"></form>';
    if( isset( $_POST['follow'] ) && strlen( $_POST['follow'] )) {add_follow_to_database();}
} else {
   echo '<form id="followsubmit" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="unfollow_button" value="unfollow">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="unfollow"></form>';
    if( isset( $_POST["unfollow"] ) && strlen( $_POST["unfollow"] )) {unfollow_button_action();}
}
}
}

function profilereportanddeletebutton($messageid, $loguser, $ownersid){
global $wpdb, $bp;
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
if ($loguser == $ownersid) {
echo '<div style="float:right;"><form action="" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="removemypost" value="' . $messageid . '"><input type="image" src="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/truth-wall/includes/images/trash.PNG" title="Delete" name="submit"></form></div>';
} else {
$check_if_already_reported = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM reported_posts WHERE postid = $messageid AND whoreported = $loguser" );
    if (empty($check_if_already_reported)) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<div id="deletebutton"><form action="" method="post" ><font color="red"><input type="hidden" name="report_this_post" value ="' . $messageid . '"><input type="image" src="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/truth-wall/includes/images/red-flag.PNG" title="Report" name="submit"></font></form> </div>';
        }
    } else {
    echo '<div id="reportedbutton">Flagged</div>';
    }
}
}
}
function publicreportanddeletebutton($messageid, $loguser, $ownersid){
global $wpdb, $bp;
if ($loguser == $ownersid) {
echo '<div style="float:right;"><form action="" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="removemypost" value="' . $messageid . '"><input type="submit" name="remove_wall_post_submit" value="Remove"></form></div>';
} else {
$check_if_already_reported = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM reported_posts WHERE postid = $messageid AND whoreported = $loguser" );
    if (empty($check_if_already_reported)) {
        echo '<div style="float:right;"><form action="" method="post" ><font color="red"><input type="hidden" name="report_this_post" value ="' . $messageid . '"><input type="image" src="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/truth-wall/includes/images/red-flag.PNG" title="Report" name="submit"></font></form></div>';
    } else {
    echo '<div style="float:right;"><font color="red" size="1">Reported</font></div>';
    }
}
}
```

That's only a few of them.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you had your multiple forms structured that were all submitting when you clicked one submit?

Comment: I edited the question to give you an example of how the data is passed around. I hope that is enough information.

Comment: you could use ajax to execute php functions. is there any reason you are not using ajax

Comment: I know I can use ajax to execute the php function. I just don't know how. I'll keep searching around for an answer.

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why are you planning on using php script inside jquery?

Comment: I have a follow button.. When it's clicked it's going to call the add_follow_to_database function.. the code inside of add_follow_to_database is `$wpdb->insert('table', array('who' => $person1, 'from' => $person2 ) array( '%d', '%d',));`

Comment: I think you need to fix your processing logic along with your forms. There is no need to do ajax from what you are describing.

Comment: I'll mess around with how everything is processed. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do all your forms look like? Can you add those as an edit?

Comment: I added more of the forms that show on the page. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with the layout of the code, I got it to work, still using

```
if(isset($_POST["input"]) &&.... {dofunction();}
```

Thank you Rasclatt for the tip. (fixing how it's processed.)

Instead of having a function store all the if(isset.. I placed each if(isset under each form it belongs to. Everything seems to be working correctly.